# How to test if a weighted graph has a negative cycle

Tags: java, graph, bellman-ford

I need to create a test that returns true if the graph (directed graph) as a parameter has a cycle of negative weight, false otherwise.

For now I created this. Theoretically should check if there are "generic" cycles, not if there are negative cycles. How can I change the method?
There's an easier or efficient?

```
//if there is a negative cycle, get out and return 
public void bellmanFord(Graph<V, E> graph, V source, V dest) {
    ArrayList<V> vertices = (ArrayList<V>) graph.getVertices();
    HashMap<V, Boolean> visited = new HashMap<V, Boolean>(vertices.size());
    for(V v : vertices) { 
        visited.put(v, false);
    }
    boolean cycle = hasNegativeCycle(graph, source, visited, vertices);
    if(cycle == true)
        return;
    else {
        ...
    }

}

public boolean hasNegativeCycle(Graph<V, E> graph, V source, HashMap<V, Boolean> visited, ArrayList<V> vertices) {
    visited.put(source, true);
    for(V u : vertices) {
      ArrayList<V> neigh_u = (ArrayList<V>) graph.getNeighbors(u);
      for(V v : neigh_u) {
        if(visited.get(v) == true || hasNegativeCycle(graph, v, visited, vertices)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks

---

EDIT: As you can see from the method name written on it, I'm trying to implement the algorithm of Bellman-Ford and I'm following this pseudocode:

```
BellmanFord(Graph G, Vertex start) { 
    foreach(Vertex u of G) { 
        dist[u] = ∞; 
        prev[u] = -1; 
    } 
    prev[start] = s; 
    dist[start] = 0; 
    repeat n times { 
        foreach(Vertex u of G) { 
            foreach(Vertex v near u) { 
                if(dist[u] + weigth_uv < dist[v]) { 
                    prev[v] = u; 
                    dist[v] = dist[u] + weigth_uv; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "negative" cycle? Do you mean at at least one of the edges has a negative-weight? Or do you mean that the sum of the weights of all the edges in a cycle are negative?

Comment: @VivinPaliath I mean that the sum of the weights of all the edges in a cycle are negative..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply Bellman-Ford Algorithm.`Wikipedia` has proper pseudocode. If you apply this properly your problem will be solved.

```
function BellmanFord(list vertices, list edges, vertex source)
   ::distance[],predecessor[]

   // This implementation takes in a graph, represented as
   // lists of vertices and edges, and fills two arrays
   // (distance and predecessor) with shortest-path
   // (less cost/distance/metric) information

   // Step 1: initialize graph
   for each vertex v in vertices:
       if v is source then distance[v] := 0
       else distance[v] := inf
       predecessor[v] := null

   // Step 2: relax edges repeatedly
   for i from 1 to size(vertices)-1:
       for each edge (u, v) in Graph with weight w in edges:
           if distance[u] + w < distance[v]:
               distance[v] := distance[u] + w
               predecessor[v] := u

   // Step 3: check for negative-weight cycles
   for each edge (u, v) in Graph with weight w in edges:
       if distance[u] + w < distance[v]:
           error "Graph contains a negative-weight cycle"
   return distance[], predecessor[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do a BFS traversal of the graph. At each node visit, record the node's unique id (.hashCode() for example, if implemented) into a HashSet. Whenever you are trying to insert an already present element into the hashset, you found a circle.

If you found a circle in say node F, you can count the circle's sum weight by traversing the tree upwards, until you find F again, and summing the weights.

Of course after determining the circle size, and it was positive, you must continue the BFS traversal, but without traversing F's children. If it was negative, return from the function, as you found a negative circle.

Edit: you can also keep track of the current sum weight during the BFS traversal steps, this way you don't have to traverse the tree upwards to calculate the total weight...As your graph is Directed, this method would fit also better...